# The maximum value is not taken into account - MicroCharts C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the QuestPDF library and MicroCharts to generate a pdf with charts.

It is happening to me that when generating the first bar graph, it does it correctly. However, if I keep generating more reports, the graph starts to look different.

Does anyone know why this could happen?

I hope you can help me.

I leave you some pictures so you understand what is happening to me:

First Report
[image: First report]

Second report
[image]

third report
[image]

I leave the part of my code where I generate the Bar Chart:

```
            List<ChartEntry> totalTransactionsByMonthsEntries = new List<ChartEntry> { };

            List<string> randomColors = new List<string> { "#5AA454", "#A10A28", "#C7B42C", "#AAAAAA", "#80DFFF", "#FF80DF", "#008000", "#4D4DFF", "#333333", "#B84DFF", "#FFAD33", "#FF1A8C" };
            var countBarColors = 0;

            foreach (var item in paymentEvolutionExportDetail.TotalTransactionsByMonths)
            {
                totalTransactionsByMonthsEntries.Add(new ChartEntry(item.Transactions)
                {
                    Label = item.Month,
                    ValueLabel = item.Transactions.ToString(),
                    Color = SKColor.Parse(randomColors[countBarColors]),
                    ValueLabelColor = SKColors.Black
                });

                countBarColors++;
            }

            var totalTransactionsByMonthsChart = new BarChart
            {
                Entries = totalTransactionsByMonthsEntries,
                LabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                ValueLabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                IsAnimated = false,
                LabelTextSize = 8,
                Margin = 10
            };

            return totalTransactionsByMonthsChart;
```

And this is the part of the PDF, where I add the chart to my document:

```
grid.Item(2)
        .PaddingLeft(-10)
        .PaddingTop(-150)
        .Width(270)
        .Border(0.5f)
        .BorderTop(0)
        .BorderColor("#A5A5A5")
        .Background("#FFFFFF")
        .Height(200)
        .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
        {
            barChart.DrawContent(canvas, 270, 200);
        });
```

I tried giving the maximum value to the chart, but this gives me the same result as shown in the images.

```
var maxTransactionValue = paymentEvolutionExportDetail.TotalTransactionsByMonths.Select(x => x.Transactions).Max();

totalTransactionsByMonthsChart.MaxValue = maxTransactionValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem by adding the bar chart generation to the PDF report generation:

```
grid.Item(2)
    .PaddingLeft(-10)
    .PaddingTop(-150)
    .Width(270)
    .Border(0.5f)
    .BorderTop(0)
    .BorderColor("#A5A5A5")
    .Background("#FFFFFF")
    .Height(200)
    .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
    {
         var barChart = new BarChart
         {
              Entries = barChartEntries,
              LabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
              ValueLabelOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
              IsAnimated = false,
              LabelTextSize = 8,
              Margin = 10
         };     
                                        
         barChart.DrawContent(canvas, 270, 200);
    });
```